# Rails: 3rd party libraries use relative CSS paths

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm using a paid bootstrapped template from wrap bootstrap (if any of you are familiar with that is) and the template uses a lot of 3rd party libraries. These libraries have relative paths in their CSS mostly for images. For example:

```
.tp-transparentimg {    content:"url(../assets/transparent.png)"}
```

I'm wondering what is the best way to handle these libraries.

Currently in my project, I'm avoiding the asset pipeline. I threw all the CSS and JS files I could find in to vendor/assets/ and I'm just having the HTML link to /asset/<.js or .css filename>

For example:

```
<!-- CSS Global Compulsory-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/header1.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/responsive.css">
```

It works but obviously any paths referenced in the CSS doesn't as I haven't changed the paths. There's about 10 libraries and I really don't want to go into each CSS file and fixing the paths. There has to be an easier way??